# connecting ESP8266 to mega 2056

Tags: arduino-mega, esp8266, java

im trying to connect wifi module to my MEGA 2560 board.
i set up the board as the picture bellow

[image: board setup]

and my program is as follows

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define DEBUG true

SoftwareSerial esp8266(18,19); // make RX Arduino line is pin 2, make TX Arduino line is pin 3.
                             // This means that you need to connect the TX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 2
                             // and the RX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 3
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600); // your esp's baud rate might be different

  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);

  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);

  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);

  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);

  sendCommand("AT+RST\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // reset module
  sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure as access point
  sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\"mySSID\",\"myPassword\"\r\n",3000,DEBUG);
  delay(10000);
  sendCommand("AT+CIFSR\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // get ip address
  sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure for multiple connections
  sendCommand("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // turn on server on port 80

  Serial.println("Server Ready");
}

void loop()
{
  if(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message 
  {


    if(esp8266.find("+IPD,"))
    {
     delay(1000); // wait for the serial buffer to fill up (read all the serial data)
     // get the connection id so that we can then disconnect
     int connectionId = esp8266.read()-48; // subtract 48 because the read() function returns 
                                           // the ASCII decimal value and 0 (the first decimal number) starts at 48

     esp8266.find("pin="); // advance cursor to "pin="

     int pinNumber = (esp8266.read()-48); // get first number i.e. if the pin 13 then the 1st number is 1
     int secondNumber = (esp8266.read()-48);
     if(secondNumber>=0 && secondNumber<=9)
     {
      pinNumber*=10;
      pinNumber +=secondNumber; // get second number, i.e. if the pin number is 13 then the 2nd number is 3, then add to the first number
     }

     digitalWrite(pinNumber, !digitalRead(pinNumber)); // toggle pin    

     // build string that is send back to device that is requesting pin toggle
     String content;
     content = "Pin ";
     content += pinNumber;
     content += " is ";

     if(digitalRead(pinNumber))
     {
       content += "ON";
     }
     else
     {
       content += "OFF";
     }

     sendHTTPResponse(connectionId,content);

     // make close command
     String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE="; 
     closeCommand+=connectionId; // append connection id
     closeCommand+="\r\n";

     sendCommand(closeCommand,1000,DEBUG); // close connection
    }
  }
}

/*
* Name: sendData
* Description: Function used to send data to ESP8266.
* Params: command - the data/command to send; timeout - the time to wait for a response; debug - print to Serial window?(true = yes, false = no)
* Returns: The response from the esp8266 (if there is a reponse)
*/
String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
    String response = "";

    int dataSize = command.length();
    char data[dataSize];
    command.toCharArray(data,dataSize);

    esp8266.write(data,dataSize); // send the read character to the esp8266
    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.println("\r\n====== HTTP Response From Arduino ======");
      Serial.write(data,dataSize);
      Serial.println("\r\n========================================");
    }

    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {

        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
        response+=c;
      }  
    }

    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);
    }

    return response;
}

/*
* Name: sendHTTPResponse
* Description: Function that sends HTTP 200, HTML UTF-8 response
*/
void sendHTTPResponse(int connectionId, String content)
{

     // build HTTP response
     String httpResponse;
     String httpHeader;
     // HTTP Header
     httpHeader = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"; 
     httpHeader += "Content-Length: ";
     httpHeader += content.length();
     httpHeader += "\r\n";
     httpHeader +="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
     httpResponse = httpHeader + content + " "; // There is a bug in this code: the last character of "content" is not sent, I cheated by adding this extra space
     sendCIPData(connectionId,httpResponse);
}

/*
* Name: sendCIPDATA
* Description: sends a CIPSEND=<connectionId>,<data> command
*
*/
void sendCIPData(int connectionId, String data)
{
   String cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
   cipSend += connectionId;
   cipSend += ",";
   cipSend +=data.length();
   cipSend +="\r\n";
   sendCommand(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
   sendData(data,1000,DEBUG);
}

/*
* Name: sendCommand
* Description: Function used to send data to ESP8266.
* Params: command - the data/command to send; timeout - the time to wait for a response; debug - print to Serial window?(true = yes, false = no)
* Returns: The response from the esp8266 (if there is a reponse)
*/
String sendCommand(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
    String response = "";

    esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266

    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {

        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
        response+=c;
      }  
    }

    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);
    }

    return response;
}
```

but i always recieve the following error

```
Arduino: 1.6.12 (Windows 7), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, 40MHz, DIO, 115200, 512K (64K SPIFFS), ck, Disabled, None"

Sketch uses 228,949 bytes (52%) of program storage space. Maximum is 434,160 bytes.
Global variables use 32,796 bytes (40%) of dynamic memory, leaving 49,124 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81,920 bytes.
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

any idea where i went wrong ?

Comment: It looks you may have badly configured your Arduino IDE: you wrote a sketch for Arduino MEGA, but the console output you show looks as if you want to upload it to the ESP8266. That sounds weird. Please show us your IDE configuration (target board) for MEGA upload.

Answer (score 1):

- Do not use SoftwareSerial on a hardware serial port. It is pointless.
- Do use a voltage divider to convert the Arduino's 5V TX to the required 3.3V the ESP8266 needs.
- Do not try and program the Arduino as if it were an ESP8266 - it won't work.

I think you are getting a little confused here...

Comment: thanks! what should i edit ? it already has a 3.3 output. i changed the board to MEGA 2560 i don`t receive this error but i get some warnings and still not working

Comment: how do you know its 3.3V. there are high odds that you might have fried you esp

Answer (score 0):

Connect your ESP directly to your PC. Test AT commands first. They will tell you if your good to go or not. Just open your serial monitor and set the baud rate to 115200. Select carriage return and type in AT. If it responds OK. Then your code is the problem. If it doesn't return OK, then your ESP or circuit is the problem.

Comment: thanks! but i cant connect esp directly to my PC. is there any way around this so i can test it with this setup'

Comment: do youn have an FTDI breakout?

Comment: sorry i don't have it . thats why i can't connect it. if its the only way i can order it. but is there any other way?

Comment: I would say that depends a lot on whether or not your ESP8266 is pre-loaded with the Espressif AT firmware. Flashing an ESP from a Arduino/MEGA is probably hard, if not impossible. If it is pre-loaded, it should respond to AT commands. As an in-between test, set the baudrate to 74880, and see if you get anything from the ESP when it's turned on, the ESP bootloader always prints info on the serial port at 74880 baud when turned on.