# ESP8266 + Arduino Mega

Tags: esp8266, arduino-mega, esp32

I am currently carrying out a project where I am using an Arduino Mega2560, to recover data from two ultrasonics sensors (HC-SR-04).
For the purpose of my project, I must add HTTP requests to this, unfortunately the Arduino Mega2560 does not allow me to connect to a WIFI.
I contacted my school, they gave me an ESP32, but as far as I understand I will not be able to connect it to my Arduino 2560?
I also have an esp8266, I found the documentation for the code, but despite many attempts (ex: [connecting ESP8266 to mega 2056](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30057/connecting-esp8266-to-mega-2056)), I cannot connect, I cannot connect it to my MEGA 2560.

Anyone have any ideas / advice?

Regards,
David

Comment: As this is a school assignment, do you really have to use the Mega for the project? They gave you an ESP32, which is way more capable than the Mega. With a 5V (depending on your exact board for example from USB) source and a voltage divider you can directly connect the HC-SR-04 to the ESP.

Comment: https://github.com/jandrassy/WiFiEspAT